# How to receive binary data using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, parameters, binary

I'm using ASP.NET MVC controllers for providing RESTful web services. That works just fine for simple data types like string and int. Now I need to send some binary data (like images and video) to this web service. My question is - what data types do I have to use as Action parameters and what else should I be aware of?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think byte[] suits any binary data. Of course, you have to know how to process it, otherwise it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Or System.Data.Linq.Binary.MVC1 Futures included LinqBinaryModelBinder.